# How to create a bootable Mac USB to install Leopard while using a Windows PC?

Tags: mac

I have a non-working Mac laptop. And I need to reinstall Mac OS X onto
it.  I have installation files for Leopard on my PC and I need to either burn a disc or create a bootable USB using my PC.

Is there any way that I can do this? And if so, how?

Comment: Which format do the files have? Do you have an .iso image or a .dmg?

Answer (score 0):

Boot up the Mac while pressing  + R to boot into the recovery partition if it is there. Make sure you are connected to internet using ethernet. If you do not have the recovery partition, burn the ISO or DMG to disc and boot up while pressing the  key. Then it will offer to boot from CD or USB.